# Swift Number Formatting conversion from Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I am very new to IOS programming so would appreciate some guidance from the Swift experts.
I have an App written in Objective-C that I am converting to Swift. It uses a custom keyboard to enter a four figure value into a textfield. Each time the user enters a digit it is divided by ten. E.g. the user enters 1 and it displays as 0.1, the user enters 12 it displays as 1.2, the user enters 123 it displays as 12.3 etc.
The Objective-C code that achieves this is:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (textviewZFW.text.length <= 4) {
        NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
        textviewZFW.text =[textviewZFW.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
        [numberFormatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:3];
        [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
        [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
        textviewZFW.text = [textviewZFW.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
        NSDecimalNumber *ZFW = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:textviewZFW.text] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]];
        textviewZFW.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:ZFW];
    }
}
```

This works just fine.

I am working through all the Swift tutorials and Apple Guide etc but have yet to achieve the same result. So far I can only get the top couple of lines to work with no decimal point:

```
@IBAction func ButtonPress1(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(ZFW.text.utf16Count <= 3){
        var digit = sender.currentTitle?

        ZFW.text = ZFW.text.stringByAppendingString(digit!)
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to write the Swift code to reflect the Objective-C above.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hope now you'll get some idea, how swift works

Swift code:

```
    if ((textviewZFW?.text.utf16Count) <= 3) {
        var digit: NSString? = sender.currentTitle
        textviewZFW?.text = textviewZFW?.text.stringByAppendingString(digit!)
        var numberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter();
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle;
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ""
        numberFormatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 3
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        textviewZFW?.text = textviewZFW?.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
        var zfwDecimal: NSDecimalNumber? = NSDecimalNumber(string: textviewZFW?.text).decimalNumberByDividingBy(NSDecimalNumber(string: "10"))
        textviewZFW?.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(zfwDecimal!)
    }
```

Comment: A million thanks, arthankamal. That works absolutely perfectly!